# PYomo "AttributeError" Message

Tags: pyomo

First, I apologize if this is not the appropriate forum for my issue. Second, I wish to state that I am new to PYomo.

That said, I have continued to experience the above-stated issue (attached is a screenshot) anytime I run my model. I have tried all I know at this point but the issue persists. I use Windows 10 with Python 3.6.3 and Pyomo version 5.2. I shall, therefore, be glad for any assistance to help fix my problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue is with your constraint name. Did you mean to call it `conOnetourEnt.N` or `conOnetourEnt`. I think removing the ".N" will fix the problem. If not, (or if you wanted the ".N" in the name) then you would need to provide more details about your model.

Comment: Hi Bethany, you are correct! The issue is with the ".N" It worked when I removed it. Thank you very much.